# Multiple equations with two implications

Tags: equations

I am trying to create this equation within LaTeX and I am extremely new to this. A longer arrow would be appreciated as well since this is originally from word. I can get the actual equations down as I'm using mathtype but I cannot seem to align a \Bigg} or even get an arrow.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use an `aligned` environment with a single extensible brace:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \left.
    \begin{aligned}
      \nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) &=
        -j \omega \mu_0 \vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) \\
      \nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) &=
         j \omega \epsilon \vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}})
    \end{aligned}
  \right\}
  \longrightarrow
  \begin{aligned}
    \nabla^2 \vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) &=
      -\omega^2 \mu_0 \epsilon \vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) \\
    \nabla^2 \vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) &=
       \omega^2 \mu_0 \epsilon \vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}})
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with the `rcases` environment from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{rcases}
      \nabla\times\vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) = -j \omega\mu_0 \vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) \\
      \nabla\times\vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) = j \omega\epsilon \vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}})
    \end{rcases}
  \longrightarrow
  \begin{aligned}
    \nabla^2 \vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) &= -\omega^2\mu_0\epsilon \vec{\mathbf{E}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) \\
    \nabla^2 \vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}}) &= \omega^2\mu_0\epsilon \vec{\mathbf{H}}(\vec{\mathbf{r}})
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]